# How to change xml drawable properties programatically

Tags: android

I use the code below as a drawable, but during runtime I want to change its color, but I can't use findViewById with the returned drawable

```
Drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.border_black);


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/theme_color">
    <shape android:id="@+id/theme_color_shape" android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:id="@+id/theme_color_solid" android:color="@color/_black" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="-5dp"
    android:right="-5dp"
    android:left="-5dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#66FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

After I receive this drawable I want to change  to other colors than black.

If you read the code carefully you will notice that this drawable consists of 2 elements / items, one should be dynamic and the other is not changable, that's why I can't use new ColorDrawable() approach.

Comment: This is a `LayerDrawable` which is a direct subclass of `Drawable` - double check by using `instanceof`, but you can get the drawables contained within on an index basis - `LayerDrawable::getDrawable(index)` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable

Comment: @MarkKeen Please put it as an answer to accept it, thank you.

Comment: @MarkKeen Please put it as an answer to accept it, thank you.